# Attempted import error: 'GoogleAuthProvider' is not exported from 'firebase/auth'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am learning React. The app was working fine yesterday. but today after I install the stripe with "**npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js**" and then it gave me suggestion to run "**npm audit fix --force**" so ran it. Then it started giving me lots of errors,
like this:

[image]

here is my firebase.js file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "---",
    authDomain: "---",
    projectId: "eshop-83328",
    storageBucket: "---",
    messagingSenderId: "---",
    appId: "---",
    measurementId: "---",
    databaseURL: "---",
  };

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

const db = getDatabase(firebaseApp);

const auth = getAuth();

export {db, auth, provider};
```

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "eshop",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.8",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.22.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

what should I do to solve this?

Comment: Can you share your package.json so we can check Firebase version ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes I shared it!

Comment: Hey @Dharmaraj, Thank you for giving the answer I really appreciate it but it didn't solve the problem. What I did to solve is that I recreated new project and created new package.json then installed all the dependency again.

Comment: Essentially, performing a clean install and ensuring the latest version is installed...?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes sir!

Answer (score 4):

You are using syntax of new Modular SDK but you still have older version of Firebase installed. Try upgrading it to latest version and restarting your dev server:

```
npm i firebase@latest
```

Also checkout ['Upgrade from version 8 to Modular SDK'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) in the documentation.